# NSSM: Creating service from a python script

Tags: python, nssm

I need to create a service from a python script, for this I am using NSSM(Non-sucking service manager). I am able to install the service using below command:
nssm install 
However when I try to start the service, it gets in Paused state.

```
nssm start <Service_Name>
```

When I try to resume/stop/restart from the services.msc it gives error like Windows could not start the service.

The python script I am using is below:

```
import sys
for i in range(sys.maxsize**10):
with open("D:\PythonWriteFile.txt","a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("Appended text")
```

Please let me know how can I make python script as service.

Comment: more details, and seems your service cannot run properly when it started.

Comment: added the script I'm using

Answer (score 0):

I am not very experienced with nssm, but on their website, they wrote:

> 2017-04-26: Users of Windows 10 Creators Update should use prelease build 2.2.4-101 to avoid an issue with services failing to start. If for some reason you cannot use that build you can also set AppNoConsole=1 in the registry, noting that applications which expect a console window may behave unexpectedly.

I'd try the version thing, perhaps this is it